# pthread_cond_wait() AND pthread_cond_signal() not working as expected

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I have example code here that I got from 
http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html

My question is

waiting on condition variable using `pthread_cond_wait()` AND
signalling the condition variable using `pthread_cond_signal()`

Can this happen only between two threads created using pthread_create? or can it happen between one thread created using pthread_create and the MAIN process(the process that calls pthread_create())

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t count_mutex     = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  condition_var   = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *functionCount1();
void *functionCount2();
int  count = 0;
#define COUNT_DONE  10
#define COUNT_HALT1  3
#define COUNT_HALT2  6

main()
{
   pthread_t thread1, thread2;

   pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, &functionCount1, NULL);
   pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, &functionCount2, NULL);

   pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
   pthread_join( thread2, NULL);

   printf("Final count: %d\n",count);

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

// Write numbers 1-3 and 8-10 as permitted by functionCount2()

void *functionCount1()
{
   for(;;)
   {
      // Lock mutex and then wait for signal to relase mutex
      pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );

      // Wait while functionCount2() operates on count
      // mutex unlocked if condition varialbe in functionCount2() signaled.
      pthread_cond_wait( &condition_var, &count_mutex );
      count++;
      printf("Counter value functionCount1: %d\n",count);

      pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );

      if(count >= COUNT_DONE) return(NULL);
    }
}

// Write numbers 4-7

void *functionCount2()
{
    for(;;)
    {
       pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );

       if( count < COUNT_HALT1 || count > COUNT_HALT2 )
       {
          // Condition of if statement has been met. 
          // Signal to free waiting thread by freeing the mutex.
          // Note: functionCount1() is now permitted to modify "count".
          pthread_cond_signal( &condition_var );
       }
       else
       {
          count++;
          printf("Counter value functionCount2: %d\n",count);
       }

       pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );

       if(count >= COUNT_DONE) return(NULL);
    }

}
```

Comment: Both of your thread proc decls are wrong. They need to take a single `void *` param. Whether you ignore that param or not is your choice. Within those procs you have unprotected evaluation of your predicate data in your `if` test after unlocking the mutex, which is an outright violation of condvar/mtx principles. *Both* problems need to be addressed.

Comment: @WhozCraig - can't I pass NULL as a parameter to the threads?

Comment: You don't pass *anything* to the threads; `pthread_create` does when it starts them. And *it* is expecting  both functions to take a `void*` as well as return one. You can certainly tell **it** to pass NULL, but the functions should still to take them as params.

Comment: @WhozCraig - I agree.I will fix that issue.But my main question is pthread_cond_wait() and pthread_cond_signal() does it work only between two processes created using pthread_create() or can it work between main process and a thread created using pthread_create()

Comment: The "main" thread is not different in any way from the "created" threads. That's one of the main ideas behind multi-threading. So you can use your condition variables and mutexes everywhere.

Comment: They're accessible and usable from any thread in the process including the main thread so all three in this case, yes).

Comment: In both thread functions concurrent access to `count` is done unprotected/unsynchronised here: `if(count >= COUNT_DONE) return(NULL);`